# Is there a way to customize word marking in html? Or how can this be achieved with other elements?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, webflow

I am working on developing a design and came across this problem where I couldn't get the exact result as wanted when it comes to the word marking.

This is what we are looking to accomplish:
https://gyazo.com/a705e6faa67e833bc3246f59ce5d3683

And this is how it currently works: It's just a div inside the text box which is moved to the right 10px and equal to the length of the word box. It works as long as the text box is not wrapping because then the length is perfect.
https://gyazo.com/41ba55f74f5b4ada80427e8c1a1a32a9

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the right idea with it. I would set the blue div to be full width (width:100%) since you want the div to stretch further on the screen.

Comment: I am a fool... I switched around the images... It's fixed now. Can you take a look at it again maybe?

Comment: Okay, then just set the blue div to be 75% width or something, and make the right margin auto.